# How do I tune my guitar like a bajo sexto

Tags: acoustic-guitar, tuning, alternative-tunings

I was just wondering how to tune my guitar to sound like a bajo sexto. I watched a video on YouTube, but it was confusing.

Comment: Hi Mercedes, welcome to the site :)
Which Youtube Video did you watch, and why did you find it confusing? You will get better answers if you show you made some effort towards finding the answer yourself.

Answer (score 2):

The bajo sexto strings are tuned in pairs, one octave lower than a typical 12-string guitar:<sup>1</sup>

```
                fourths
  |------|------|------|------|------|

E1-E2  A1-A2  D2-D3  G2-G2  C3-C3  F3-F3 2

|_________________|  |_________________|
     octaves               unison
```

---

This post is distilled from the Wikipedia page on [Bajo sexto tuning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bajo_sexto#Construction_and_tuning).

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>For help tuning a guitar down an octave, see [Is it possible to tune guitar down an octave?(or to f#?)](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/43322/is-it-possible-to-tune-guitar-down-an-octaveor-to-f)</sub>

<sup>2</sup> <sub>For more on scientific pitch notation (E1, F3, etc.), see [What do the terms E2 A2 D3 G3 B3 E4 actually mean?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/32715/what-do-the-terms-e2-a2-d3-g3-b3-e4-actually-mean)</sub>

Comment: Normal 12 string guitars have an octave G, but unison B and E, due to the string tension problem there. Any idea why bajo doesn't have *all* strings in octaves - no tension problems there?

Comment: @Tim Maybe just to preserve the bass range of the instrument?

Answer (score -1):

Just play with the top 4 strings

Comment: I'm unclear why using the top 4 strings is the best way to emulate the tuning of a 12-string instrument?